# PHP loop through array, sort by week and count the weekly working hours

Tags: php, foreach, processwire

Im looping through my childpages and I get the table but now I need to sort and sum the working hours for each week.

This is my code so far:

```
    $hours = $pages->find('template=arbetstimmar, sort='.$sort.','.$find.', userid='.$uid.',workdate>='.$startd.',workdate<='.$stopd);
    foreach ($hours as $h){?>
    <?php
    $th = $h->worktime + $th; //totalhours
    $tp = $h->worktime * $h->priceperhour;
    $tc = $tp + $tc;
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($h->workdate));
    $week = date('W', strtotime($date));
    $dow = date('w', strtotime($date));
    $week = (int)$week;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><b>(<?php echo $week;?>) <?= $h->workdate;?></b></td>
        <td><a href="<?= $h->parent->url;?>#<?=$h->id;?>"><?php echo $h->parent->parent->parent->title. " > ";echo $h->parent->parent->title. " > "; echo $h->parent->title;  ?></a></td>
        <td><?= $h->workexplanation;?></td>
        <td><?= number_format($h->worktime, 2, '.', '')?>h</td>
        <td><?= number_format($h->priceperhour, 2, '.', '')?>€</td>
    </tr>
      <?php }?>
```

[The output looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Lm8.png)

As I explained I'm trying to sum the hours for each week.

I have tried with if and while statements but can't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I get the weeks separated:

```
  $last_date =null;
  $weeklyhours = 0;
  $hours = $pages->find('template=arbetstimmar, sort='.$sort.','.$find.', userid='.$uid.',workdate>='.$startd.',workdate<='.$stopd);
  foreach ($hours as $h){?>
  <?php
  $th = $h->worktime + $th; //totalhours
  $tp = $h->worktime * $h->priceperhour;
  $tc = $tp + $tc;
  $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($h->workdate));
  $week = date('W', strtotime($date));
  $week = (int)$week;
  ?>
  <?php
  if ( $last_date != $week ) {
    $weeklyhours = $h->worktime + $weeklyhours;?>
    <tr style="background: #f8f8f8;">
      <td>Vecka: <?= $week;?></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><?= $weeklyhours;?></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><b><?= $h->workdate;?></b></td>
      <td><a href="<?= $h->parent->url;?>#<?=$h->id;?>"><?php echo $h->parent->parent->parent->title. " > ";echo $h->parent->parent->title. " > "; echo $h->parent->title;  ?></a></td>
      <td><?= $h->workexplanation;?></td>
      <td><?= number_format($h->worktime, 2, '.', '')?>h</td>
      <td><?= number_format($h->priceperhour, 2, '.', '')?>€</td>
  </tr>

  <?php }
  else if ( $last_date == $week ){
    $weeklyhours = $h->worktime + $weeklyhours;
  ?>

  <tr>
      <td><b><?= $h->workdate;?></b></td>
      <td><a href="<?= $h->parent->url;?>#<?=$h->id;?>"><?php echo $h->parent->parent->parent->title. " > ";echo $h->parent->parent->title. " > "; echo $h->parent->title;  ?></a></td>
      <td><?= $h->workexplanation;?></td>
      <td><?= number_format($h->worktime, 2, '.', '')?>h</td>
      <td><?= number_format($h->priceperhour, 2, '.', '')?>€</td>
  </tr>

  <?php }
```

The problem now is that I can't get the summary of the hours per each week.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
    $weeklyhours = 0;
// NEW LINE HERE - Create an array to use.
$hoursPerWeek = [];
$hours = $pages->find('template=arbetstimmar, sort='.$sort.','.$find.', userid='.$uid.',workdate>='.$startd.',workdate<='.$stopd);
foreach ($hours as $h){?>
<?php
$th = $h->worktime + $th; //totalhours
$tp = $h->worktime * $h->priceperhour;
$tc = $tp + $tc;
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($h->workdate));
$week = date('W', strtotime($date));
$week = (int)$week;
// NEW LINE HERE - Add to array.
$hoursPerWeek[$week] += $h->worktime;
?>
<?php
if ( $last_date != $week ) {?>
  <tr style="background: #f8f8f8;">
    <td>Vecka: <?= $week;?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><?= $hoursPerWeek[$week];?></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td><b><?= $h->workdate;?></b></td>
    <td><a href="<?= $h->parent->url;?>#<?=$h->id;?>"><?php echo $h->parent->parent->parent->title. " > ";echo $h->parent->parent->title. " > "; echo $h->parent->title;  ?></a></td>
    <td><?= $h->workexplanation;?></td>
    <td><?= number_format($h->worktime, 2, '.', '')?>h</td>
    <td><?= number_format($h->priceperhour, 2, '.', '')?>€</td>
</tr>

<?php }
else if ( $last_date == $week ){?>

<tr>
    <td><b><?= $h->workdate;?></b></td>
    <td><a href="<?= $h->parent->url;?>#<?=$h->id;?>"><?php echo $h->parent->parent->parent->title. " > ";echo $h->parent->parent->title. " > "; echo $h->parent->title;  ?></a></td>
    <td><?= $h->workexplanation;?></td>
    <td><?= number_format($h->worktime, 2, '.', '')?>h</td>
    <td><?= number_format($h->priceperhour, 2, '.', '')?>€</td>
</tr>

<?php } 
//echo $h->workdate."-".$weeklyhours;
$last_date = $week;
?>
        <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and easy way to "sum" the hours per week is by having an array that has the week as the key, and the value as the sum of hours.

In your example i would in your 'foreach' do following:

```
<?php
// NEW LINE HERE - Create an array to use.
$hoursPerWeek = [];

$hours = $pages->find('template=arbetstimmar, sort='.$sort.','.$find.', userid='.$uid.',workdate>='.$startd.',workdate<='.$stopd);
foreach ($hours as $h){?>
<?php
$th = $h->worktime + $th; //totalhours
$tp = $h->worktime * $h->priceperhour;
$tc = $tp + $tc;
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($h->workdate));
$week = date('W', strtotime($date));
$dow = date('w', strtotime($date));
$week = (int)$week;

// NEW LINE HERE - Add to array.
$hoursPerWeek[$week] += $h->worktime;
?>
<tr>
    <td><b>(<?php echo $week;?>) <?= $h->workdate;?></b></td>
    <td><a href="<?= $h->parent->url;?>#<?=$h->id;?>"><?php echo $h->parent->parent->parent->title. " > ";echo $h->parent->parent->title. " > "; echo $h->parent->title;  ?></a></td>
    <td><?= $h->workexplanation;?></td>
    <td><?= number_format($h->worktime, 2, '.', '')?>h</td>
    <td><?= number_format($h->priceperhour, 2, '.', '')?>€</td>
</tr>
  <?php }?>
```

So what I'm doing here is to store the hours in an array, on each key which is your week.

To avoid some PHP warnings, you might wanne make sure key on the array is created before you add value to it..

Hope it makes sense.

EDIT: To update your code, to fix your problem, and also to clean your code abit, I think this would do it for you.

```
<?php
// Our data source.
$hours = $pages->find('template=arbetstimmar, sort='.$sort.','.$find.', userid='.$uid.',workdate>='.$startd.',workdate<='.$stopd);

// We need to loop through the array first to use the summed up value later.
$hoursPerWeek = [];
foreach ($hours as $h) {
    $hoursPerWeek[$week] += $h->worktime;
}


$last_date = 0;
$weeklyhours = 0;

// Loop hours again, now make the output.
foreach ($hours as $h) {
    $th = $h->worktime + $th; //totalhours
    $tp = $h->worktime * $h->priceperhour;
    $tc = $tp + $tc;
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($h->workdate));
    $week = date('W', strtotime($date));
    $week = (int)$week;

    // Previous, was the last of that week.

    if ($last_date != $week) {
    ?>

        <tr style="background: #f8f8f8;">
             <td>Vecka: <?= $week;?></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td><?=$hoursPerWeek[$week];?></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>

     <?php
     }

     $last_date = $week;

     // Create a output for our current hourlog.
     ?>

     <tr>
         <td><b><?= $h->workdate;?></b></td>
         <td><a href="<?= $h->parent->url;?>#<?=$h->id;?>"><?php echo $h->parent->parent->parent->title. " > ";echo $h->parent->parent->title. " > "; echo $h->parent->title;  ?></a></td>
         <td><?= $h->workexplanation;?></td>
         <td><?= number_format($h->worktime, 2, '.', '')?>h</td>
         <td><?= number_format($h->priceperhour, 2, '.', '')?>€</td>
     </tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Aprilsnar! I get the idea, but I have a problem when I get the same weeks multiple times in the foreach loop. Eg. I get 49,49, 50,50, 51,51,51 etc. I tried to use the array_unique with implode but can't get the weeks only once. 

$weeks = implode(' ',array_unique(explode(' ', $week)));

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to sum the hours together on the week? The line $hoursPerWeek[$week] += $h->worktime; would sum the together because of the += but I might be misunderstanding your question here..

Comment: Yes, but I I echo $hoursPerWeek[$week]; I get the following: 2 5 24 26 38 61 73 2 14 26. Week52 there are 2 worktimes 2, 3 = 5, then week 51 5 worktimes, 24, 2, 12, 23, 12 = 73, week 49 3 worktimes, 2, 12, 12 = 26. So the problems is that it kind sums the hours but it doesn't sum the hours correctly.

Comment: Are you able to post the output of following:  var_dump($hoursPerWeek);

Comment: Yes, this is my result:
array(1) { [52]=> float(2) } array(1) { [52]=> float(5) } array(2) { [52]=> float(5) [51]=> float(24) } array(2) { [52]=> float(5) [51]=> float(26) } array(2) { [52]=> float(5) [51]=> float(38) } array(2) { [52]=> float(5) [51]=> float(61) } array(2) { [52]=> float(5) [51]=> float(73) } array(3) { [52]=> float(5) [51]=> float(73) [49]=> float(2) } array(3) { [52]=> float(5) [51]=> float(73) [49]=> float(14) } array(3) { [52]=> float(5) [51]=> float(73) [49]=> float(26) }

Comment: I might know what's wrong, but it depends on your current code. Maybe you will update it above?

Comment: Thanks. Okay so the problem is you need to let the foreach go through all children in $hours  before you can echo out something from it (or else you would not get the summed value). Another easy but not as clean fix would be to have two foreach (seperated) where the first should only contain $week = (int)$week; and $hoursPerWeek[$week] += $h->worktime; as so the summed value would be whole. In your next foreach you can then just delete those lines and echo the value from the above created foreach.

Comment: Thank you! I created a separated foreach before this and the results are correct! Thank you so much! How do I accept your latest comment as the answer?

Comment: Just accept the answer above the comment - I will update it with the result for your scenario when I get on a computer again.